# How to set common labels with matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, axes

I have a plot obtained in this way:

```
f, ((ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4), (ax5, ax6, ax7, ax8), (ax9, ax10, ax11, ax12)) = plt.subplots(3, 4, sharex = 'col', sharey = 'row')
ax1.set_title('column1')
ax1.plot([x], [y])
ax5.plot([x1],[y1])
ax9.plot([x2],[y2])
.....
```

so, I essentially have 3 rows and 4 columns.
I would like to know how is it possible to put commond labels to the x and y axis. 
I tried to write

```
 plt_xlabel('x')
 plt.ylabel('y')
```

or

```
 set.xlabel('x')
 set.ylabel('y')
```

but it doesn't work. Can you help me? Is it also possible to put text on the right end side of the plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by iterating over your list of axes:

```
f, ax_lst  =  plt.subplots(3, 4, sharex = 'col', sharey = 'row')
for ax_l in ax_lst:
    for ax in ax_l:
        ax.set_xlabel('x')
        ax.set_ylabel('y')
```

Comment: tanx for your answer. I solved the problem. Do you also know ho is it possible to insert text outside the plot window? For each row I would like to write a sentence on the right end side of the plot.

Comment: If this solved your problem you should accept the answer (big check mark on the left.   Your second question really deserves a question of it's own.